# Gambler's ruin problem: How to show that the probability of winning or losing is 1?

Tags: probability

In the gambler's ruin problem, let $p$ be the probability that gambler A will win 1 dollar from gambler B and $q=1-p$ be the probability that gambler B will win 1 dollar from gambler A. Let A has initial fortune of $i$ dollars and B has $k-i$ dollars. Then the probability that fortune of gambler A will reach $k$ dollars before it reaches $0$ dollars is $$\dfrac{\left(\frac qp\right)^{i}-1}{\left(\frac qp\right)^k-1}$$ if $p\neq q$.Then isn't the probability that the fortune of gambler B will reach $k$ dollars before it reaches $0$ dollars $$1-\dfrac{\left(\frac qp\right)^{i}-1}{\left(\frac qp\right)^k-1}?$$ And as for A's case , shouldn't it be $$\dfrac{\left(\frac pq\right)^{k-i}-1}{\left(\frac pq\right)^k-1}?$$

So how to show that this holds?
$$1-\dfrac{\left(\frac pq\right)^{k-i}-1}{\left(\frac pq\right)^k-1}=\dfrac{\left(\frac qp\right)^{i}-1}{\left(\frac qp\right)^k-1}$$ where $p,q>0$ and $p+q=1$ and $i$ and $k$ and $k-i$ are natural numbers?

Comment: @Newb, I have added the reason of the question. Please let me know where am i wrong.

Comment: I can't say. You might be right, I don't know. I worked with it for a while and couldn't get to a conclusion, but maybe I just approached it from the wrong angle. Maybe someone else can help you out. Maybe I'll give it another try later.

Comment: @Newb, no problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{Use the identity}\ 1-\dfrac{x^{k-i}-1}{x^k-1}=\dfrac{x^k-x^{k-i}}{x^k-1}=\dfrac{1-\left(\frac1x\right)^i}{1-\left(\frac1x\right)^k}\ \text{with}\ x=\frac{p}q.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
\dfrac{\left(\frac qp\right)^{i}-1}{\left(\frac qp\right)^k-1} = \dfrac{\left(\frac qp\right)^{i}\left(\frac pq\right)^k-\left(\frac pq\right)^k}{\left(\frac qp\right)^k\left(\frac pq\right)^k-\left(\frac pq\right)^k}
$$
Note that $\left(\frac qp\right)=\left(\frac pq\right)^{-1}$.